# How to create new list of lists using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have two lists like

```
values = [['bert', '1234', 'xxx', 50], ['ernie', '5678', 'fff', 100]]
required = [1, 3]
```

I want to extract the `required` elements 1 and 3 from each list contained in `values`, to create a new list of lists like `[['1234', 50], ['5678', 100]]`.

I was able to solve the problem with a list comprehension:

```
[[x[y] for y in required] for x in values]
```

But **how can I write the equivalent with explicit `for` loops?**

I tried:

```
new_list = []
for x in values:
    for y in required:
        new_list.append(x[y])
```

but the resulting `new_list` is a single flat list `['1234', 50, '5678', 100]`.

Comment: Hint: what would the unrolled code look like for `[x[y] for y in required]`? Now, what do you need to do *with the lists created by that code* in order to build the desired overall result? "I'm new to Python and have looked up other articles but can't seem to find the solution to my problem." That's because it *isn't a question about how to write Python code*; it's a question about *logic and reasoning*. Anyway, please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; we want questions to be direct, without [conversational language](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721).

Comment: (Please see how I [edit]ed the post in order to understand how to ask clearly and directly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new array before second looping, and then add x[y] in that array. Add the new array to the new_list after the second looping.

```py
new_list = [] 
for x in values:
    temp_list = []
    for y in required:
       temp_list.append(x[y])
    new_list.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: Thank you Chelsafv for your solution - that works nicely - I get it now. It's funny I was able to get the list comprehension but couldn't unpack it in the explicit for loop. I see the logic now as hinted to by Karl above. And thanks too Nick for the edit to remove the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain index (and list comprehension):

```py
values = [['bert', '1234', 'xxx', 50], ['ernie', '5678', 'fff', 100]]
required = [1, 3]

output = [[sublst[i] for i in required] for sublst in values]

print(output) # [['1234', 50], ['5678', 100]]
```

Using `operator.itemgetter`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

values = [['bert', '1234', 'xxx', 50], ['ernie', '5678', 'fff', 100]]
required = [1, 3]

output = [itemgetter(*required)(sublst) for sublst in values]

print(output) # [('1234', 50), ('5678', 100)]
```